# Cannot find the main window handle of the just stareted Dialog APP

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, win32gui

Here is the scenario:

I have 2 apps. One of them is my main app, and the second is a dialog based app, which is started from the first one. I'm trying to capture the main handle of the dialog based app from my main app. The problem is that I cannot find it with EnumWindows. The problem disappears if I put sleep for a second, just before start enumerating windows.

This is the code:

```
...

BOOL res = ::CreateProcess( NULL, _T("MyApp.exe"), NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &siStartInfo, &piProcInfo );
ASSERT(res);
dwErr = WaitForInputIdle(piProcInfo.hProcess, iTimeout); 
ASSERT(dwErr == 0);

//Sleep(1000); //<-- uncomment this will fix the problem

DWORD dwProcessId = piProcInfo.dwProcessId; 
EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, (LPARAM)&dwProcessId);
....

BOOL IsMainWindow(HWND handle)
{
   return GetWindow(handle, GW_OWNER) == (HWND)0 && IsWindowVisible(handle);
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND  hwnd,   LPARAM  lParam)
{
    DWORD* pParam = (DWORD*)lParam;
    DWORD dwTargetProcessId = *pParam;
    DWORD dwProcessId = 0;
    ::GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwProcessId);

   if (dwProcessId == dwTargetProcessId )
    {
      TCHAR buffer[MAXTEXT];
      ::SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)MAXTEXT,(LPARAM)buffer);

      if( IsMainWindow(hwnd))      
      {
          g_hDlg = hwnd;
          return FALSE;
      }
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

There are exactly 2 windows which belongs to my process and tracing their text shows:

```
GDI+ Window
Default IME
```

I'm not quite sure what does this mean. These might be the default captions, assigned to the windows, before their initialization.... but I call EnumWindows after WaitForInputIdle ...

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to explain what is "main window"? How is it different from another top-level window?

Comment: Hi, By main window I mean the main window:). Those who handle all others. In this case the main window is Dialog.

Comment: This is like saying "by that window I mean THAT window" :) What is so special about the window you called "main"? How can you tell it apart from other windows, like "GDI+ Window"?

Comment: Okay, I might not be very correct by using the term of "main window"  for the Dialog Window, which is created by CreateWindow. E.g. this is the parent base window, meaning that all other windows are its children.

Comment: All of the windows are created by CreateWindow(). None of the child windows are enumerated by EnumWindows(). You need to find something else that sets your "main" window apart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CreateProcess` returns, when the OS has created the process object including the object representing the primary thread. This does not imply, that the process has started execution.

If you need to query another process for information that is only available after that process has run to a certain point, you will need to install some sort of synchronization. An obvious option is a named event object (see [CreateEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396.aspx)), that is signaled, when the second process has finished its initialization, and the dialog is up and running. The first process would then simply [WaitForSingleProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032.aspx), and only continue, once the event is signaled. (A more robust solution would call [WaitForMultipleObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025.aspx) on both the event and the process handle, to respond to unexpected process termination.)

Another option would be to have the second process send a user-defined message (`WM_APP+x`) to the first process, passing its `HWND` along.

---

[WaitForInputIdle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687022.aspx) sounds like a viable solution. Except, it isn't. `WaitForInputIdle` was introduced to meet the requirements of DDE, and merely checks, if a thread in the target process can receive messages. And that really means **any** thread in that process. It is not strictly tied to a GUI being up and running.

Additional information on the topic can be found here:

- [WaitForInputIdle should really be called WaitForProcessStartupComplete](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/25/9984720.aspx)
- [WaitForInputIdle waits for any thread, which might not be the thread you care about](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/26/9985422.aspx)

Comment: And for that reason i use WaitForInputIdle. According to the MSDN:

WaitForInputIdle :
Waits until the specified process has finished processing its initial input and is waiting for user input with no input pending,

Comment: Ha, thanks for this help :). Indeed WaitForInputIdle doesn't work as  expected, at least not for single thread apps.. And I agree that better solution will be to introduce Events.